# Can i use the Azure DNS Service for my private network(s)?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, azure

I have the following situation:

- An extranet with multiple internal network zones, with private ip ranges (10.x.x.x (subnetted), 192.168.x.x.x etc..).
- These networks are connected using dedicated / private network connections and traffic can be routed to / from these network zones.

I want to use DNS across these networks, so services across these network zones can be found reliably (without resorting to ip addresses).

I have multiple internal websites and services i want to use; for example:

```
10.10.1.2   -> myservice.corp.net
192.168.4.5 -> mysite.corp.net
```

Can I use the Azure DNS services to register and resolve these internal network addresses? What is required (express route for example) to enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register whatever you like in Azure DNS, but there are two caveats for the scenario you describe. The domain names you use will have to be fully delegated and the DNS records will be resolvable by anyone who knows the domain name.

Comment: So there is no restriction to public IP-address?

Comment: no, an A-record can store any IPv4 value and a AAAA-record can store any IPv6 address.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since you seem affiliated with Azure DNS, could you possibly tell when Azure DNS will golive, and if using private IP ranges will continue to be supported?